# What files/folders should I restore after a clean install to get core Apple apps (Mail etc) back to their previous state?

Tags: restore, install

I'm about to embark on a clean install of Mavericks. This is the first clean install I've done in *years*, and OSX has undergone quite a few evolutions in that time, so I want to check a few things against the group wisdom before I start.

The object of the clean install is not to make my working mac a completely blank slate, but to clear out the cruft. Thus I'll be reinstalling *most* things and will want to get the day-to-day stuff (Mail, Safari, Calendar, Contacts, Notes, print setup, etc) back to the same working environment that I have before the install. With that in mind, and focusing on OSX-native apps (I'll reinstall the third-party apps fresh and pull in prefs etc from backup as necessary), can anyone please confirm that these are the user-specific/library files that I should be restoring from backup?:

**Mail:**

`~/Library/Mail
~/Library/Mail/Mail Downloads
~/Library/Application Support/Mail`

**Calendar:**

`~/Library/Calendars`

**Safari:**

`~/Library/Safari`

*(will this snag all Safari's extensions and their settings too?)*

**Messages:**

`~/Library/Messages`

**Notes:**

`??? I have no idea where notes on the Mac are stored`

**Contacts:**

`~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook`

*(alternatively, if I simply let iCloud take care of that, will it successfully bring in all my groups and smart sets as well?)*

**Other supporting files:**

`~/Library/Preferences/ -any com.apple preferences-
~/Library/Saved Application State/ -any appropriate com.apple. files- 
~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync`

*(will this successfully hook up my existing device backups with iTunes?)*

**Have I missed anything else?**

EDIT:

Also: would people advise de-authorising the machine in iTunes and iBooks before doing the clean install (assuming that I am most likely going to reformat the hard drive as part of the process)? I can't remember whether a reformat causes the iTunes and iBook stores to treat the Mac as a new machine.

Comment: What version of OS X do you currently have installed.

Comment: Mavericks. I'm doing a straight Mav -> Mav clean install.

Comment: One troublesome folder you've left out is ~Library/Containers where Mail stores its downloaded attachments, Messages stores its archive, and a bunch of other things.  A simpler(?) way might be to just copy everything from ~/Library except for the Caches/ folder.  That might not be as clean as you'd hoped for though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about Containers, Kent, that's very good to know. And although it would be simplest just to copy back the entire ~/Library folder, that's precisely where most of the detritus and cruft builds up over time, so I really want to only bring back the stuff that's needed. Else there's just too much old junk from old, deleted apps and what have you and I may as well not have bothered with the clean install at all.